# Please Save My Name

Tags: java, strings, game, file, libgdx

I wanted to create a save game system for my city building game that did not require the player to input a name for the city. It was also important to allow infinite save games, so I could not just use save slots to solve the problem. With a bit of help, I devised a system that would allow the player to optionally enter a name, and if they didn't the game would determine a default name based on the existing save names.

At first I was just counting all of the existing worlds and then adding that number to `"world"` to get the name. However, I was concerned about the edge case where someone would, for example, make 5 worlds, then delete `"world4"`, and then the game would suggest the name `"world5"` again, and if the player wasn't paying attention, their save would be overwritten.

When the user chooses to start a new game, a TextField appears that is populated by the correct string, which would be `"world"` followed by the next unused number.

```
String startName = this.getFirstUnusuedWorldName(this.getNumWorlds());
this.worldNameField = new TextField(startName, this.skin);
```

Here is the `getNumWorlds()` method:

```
private int getNumWorlds() {
    FileHandle[] files = Gdx.files.local("worlds/").list();
    int numDirectories = 0;
    for (FileHandle handle : files) {
        if (handle.isDirectory()) {
            numDirectories++;
        }
    }
    return numDirectories;
}
```

And here is the `getFirstUnusuedWorldName` method:

```
private String getFirstUnusuedWorldName(int numWorlds) {
    FileHandle[] files = Gdx.files.local("worlds/").list();
    if (files.length == 0) {
        return "world1";
    }

    ArrayList<String> possibleNames = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (int i = 1; i <= numWorlds + 1; i++) { //world names start with 1, need to search 1 past length
        possibleNames.add("world" + String.valueOf(i));
    }
    for (String possibleName : possibleNames) {
        boolean containsName = false;
        for (FileHandle file : files) {
            if (file.name().equals(possibleName)) {
                containsName = true;
            }
        }
        if (!containsName) {
            return possibleName;
        }
    }

    return "world1";
}
```

I'm hoping there's a better way to do this.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You manage to do the right thing, but the way that you do it is a bit... what shall we say...? twisted? backwards? non-optimal!

Your approach:

- Get list of all files in directory
- Loop over a range and add the possible names to a list
- Loop through the possible names and check if it matches an existing file

My comments to that:

- Using the correct data structures would help greatly here. Adding the existing file names to a `Set<String>` will make the lookup time \$O(1)\$.
- Adding the names to a list is just completely unnecessary as you loop through that list directly afterwards.
- Looping through a specific range is also unnecessary. Start loop from 1 and just don't stop until you have found a free spot.
- This will also make the special-case `files.length == 0` unnecessary.

Here's what we can end up with:

```
private String getFirstUnusuedWorldName() {
    FileHandle[] files = Gdx.files.local("worlds/").list();
    Set<String> fileNames = new HashSet<String>();
    for (FileHandle handle : files) {
        fileNames.add(handle.getName());
    }

    for (int i = 1; ; i++) {
        String name = "world" + i;
        if (!fileNames.contains(name)) {
            return name;
        }
    }
}
```

Note the lack of a stopping condition in the `for`-loop (You don't need one as sooner or later, there will be an empty spot).

Also note that you no longer need the `int numWorlds` parameter.

Answer (score 4):

Edited thanks to @Quill.

Assuming that the player doesn't care about the name allocated to the file, browsing the filetree and making exceptions for possible user interactions seems like a lot of work.

You appear to be searching for a unique string to add to the base world name. One is readily available in the form of a timestamp, for example `world20150709132530`  based on the base world name, year, month, hour, minute and second. I'm sorry not to be able to provide a code example as I'm not familiar with the language, but this should be readily available in the reference documents.

Possible dangers associated with this alternate method include moving to a different time zone, summer time or clock resyncs. In all cases, a problem occurs if the user saves in the 'same second' in the new timeframe as they did in the previous timeframe. Using UTC eliminates the first two errors, but adds a layer of confusion for the user if they look at the filenames from a country not currently in the UTC timezone.

Comment: The name is used to populate a TextField that is visible to the player, so it is better in my case not to use a strange number. Interesting approach though!

Comment: is `world-2015-Jul-09-T13:25:30` better? using e.g. `String filename = new SimpleDateFormat("'world'-yyyy-MMM-dd-'T'HH:mm:ss").format(new Date());`

Comment: @pbeentje I don't think there's a OS in the world that allows `:` in a filename.

Comment: @SimonAndréForsberg Any OS following the filename rules of The Single Unix Specification allows any character except NUL and forward slash. This includes both OS X and Linux, which are the basis for iOS and Android respectively. See the [Open Group Base Specifications](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007904875/basedefs/xbd_chap03.html#tag_03_169).